# .txt read in python find character and word count using a loop

Tags: python, loops

Your program will read / open this file

As you read this file, display the each line to the screen with a line number

At the end of your program, you display some statistics of the file which must include the Line Count and Character Count, feel free to add more.

To calculate the Character Count, and Word Count *DO NOT* use any built-in functions to solve this for you such as len, split or regular expressions.

```
# try to solve this with a loop 

def gen_lines():
    with open("file_x.txt", "r") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            yield line
```

im so lost

Comment: `im so lost` — please provide an error / specific problem you have with your script

Comment: Dont post your assignments on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have txt file called `input.txt` with the following contents:

```
apple
banana
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
cherry
```

Consider writing a function that takes in a path of a file, opens it, and uses a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) over each line:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def process_file(file_path: Path) -> None:
  """Process a text file and display its content and statistics.
    
     This function reads the text file line by line, displays each line with its
     line number, and provides statistics like line count, character count, and 
     word count without using built-in functions like len, split, or regex.
    
     Args:
         file_path: The path to the text file to be processed.

     Returns:
         None: The function prints the content and statistics, but doesn't return anything.
  """
  line_count = 0
  char_count = 0
  word_count = 0
  with open(file_path, "r") as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
      line_count += 1
      print(f"Line {line_count}: {line.strip()}")
      # Character Count without using len()
      for char in line:
        char_count += 1 if char != '\n' else 0
      # Word Count without using split()
      in_word = False
      for char in line:
        if char.isalnum():
          in_word = True
        elif in_word:
          word_count += 1
          in_word = False
      # Handle the case where the line ends with a word
      if in_word:
        word_count += 1
  print(f"Line Count: {line_count}")
  print(f"Character Count: {char_count}")
  print(f"Word Count: {word_count}")


def main() -> None:
  # Run the function on the sample file
  process_file(Path("input.txt"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

**Output:**

```
Line 1: apple
Line 2: banana
Line 3: the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
Line 4: cherry
Line Count: 4
Character Count: 61
Word Count: 12
```